# Serving static files from S3 bucket not working?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have configured an S3 bucket to store and serve static and media files for a Django website, currently just trying to get the static files needed for the admin pages and all that.

Here is all the static and AWS config info in my settings file:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'config.storage_backends.MediaStorage'

#used to authenticate with S3
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'AKIAWWJOJKZGFSJO2UPW' #not real one
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'KNg1z5wXWiDRAIh4zLiHgbD2N3wtWZTK' #not real one

#for endpoints to send or retrieve files
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'my-static' #not real bucket name
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com'
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',}
AWS_LOCATION = 'static'

STATIC_ROOT = 'static'
STATIC_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{AWS_LOCATION}/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'config/static'),
]
```

Of course I replaced any sensitive variables with fake ones for the purpose of this post. I have gone through many tutorials and other posts and I seem to have my STATIC_URL configured correctly but whenever I runserver and go to the admin pages, none of the css is applied. I do not think it is properly retrieving the static files (they are all uploaded to the S3 bucket) from the bucket, but I am stuck on what to do.

Comment: Have you run ***`python manage.py collectstatic`*** command?

Comment: If your app is running on EC2, ideally you should remove the IAM user credentials completely and rely on an IAM role, which the EC2 instance is launched with ([example](https://blog.bitlabstudio.com/ultra-short-guide-to-django-and-amazon-s3-2c5aae805ce4)).

Comment: @ArakkalAbu yes I have, all static files transferred over to the bucket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I am sure you might have missed some configurations like public and static file hosting on your s3 bucket.
- Please go through this article [Using Amazon S3 to Store your Django Site's Static and Media Files](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/11/10/Using-Amazon-S3-to-store-your-Django-sites-static-and-media-files/#s3-bucket-access)
- I have personally tried this and it worked for me. The article explains every step.